# Filtering of driver id

Tags: javascript

What I want is if driver is in BusyAgent so the final output for freedriver should contain all enteries from fetchAgent  except 
those in busyAgent.

**Expected output
[{"tag":"","array":[{"device_type":0,"fleet_id":23691,"eta":0}]}]**

```
var fetchAgent = [{
    "tag": "",
    "array": [{
        "device_type": 0,
        "fleet_id": 24117,
        "eta": 0
    }]
}, {
    "tag": "",
    "array": [{
        "device_type": 0,
        "fleet_id": 23691,
        "eta": 0
    }]
}];


var busyAgent = ['24102', '24103', '24117'];

//Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

if (Array.isArray(busyAgent) && busyAgent.length > 0) {
    freeDrivers = fetchAgent.map(e => {
        e.array = e.array.filter(a => busyAgent.indexOf("" + a.fleet_id))
        return e;
    });
} else {
    freeDrivers = fetchAgent;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(freeDrivers));
```

Comment: to which number does `23691` match?

Comment: exactly it doesnt match to any case so it should display as final output @ Nina Scholz

Comment: is it right, that you mutate the `array` property by filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the filter case, and perhaps replace `map` with `filter` as well so you don't have null values. Otherwise, you will have to do another filtering down the road.

```js
var fetchAgent = [{
    "tag": "",
    "array": [{
        "device_type": 0,
        "fleet_id": 24117,
        "eta": 0
    }]
}, {
    "tag": "",
    "array": [{
        "device_type": 0,
        "fleet_id": 23691,
        "eta": 0
    }]
}];


var busyAgent = ['24102', '24103', '24117'];
if (Array.isArray(busyAgent) && busyAgent.length > 0) {
    freeDrivers = fetchAgent.filter(e => {
        e.array = e.array.filter(a => busyAgent.indexOf("" + a.fleet_id) < 0);
        if( e.array.length > 0) return e;
    });
} else {
    freeDrivers = fetchAgent;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(freeDrivers));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using Array's `filter()` in a more simpler way:

```js
var fetchAgent = [{
    "tag": "",
    "array": [{
        "device_type": 0,
        "fleet_id": 24117,
        "eta": 0
    }]
}, {
    "tag": "",
    "array": [{
        "device_type": 0,
        "fleet_id": 23691,
        "eta": 0
    }]
}];


var busyAgent = ['24102', '24103', '24117'];

var output = fetchAgent.filter(function(item){
  return !busyAgent.includes(item.array[0].fleet_id.toString())
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```